# Unable to load dataframe from elasticsearch 6.4.1

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get dataframe from elastic search, i am using these versions:
python 3.7
spark 2.3.1
pyspark 2.3.1
elaseticsearch 6.4.1

pip packages:
urllib3==1.26.15
python_dotenv
termcolor
uuid
elasticsearch==6.4.0

what is the steps that i need to follow to fix the error

```
import json
from os import getenv

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext


class BaseEngine:

    __instance = None

    # region used to set elasticsearch Hadoop RDD
    INPUT_FORMAT_CLASS = "org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat"
    OUTPUT_FORMAT_CLASS = "org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat"
    KEY_CLASS = "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable"
    VALUE_CLASS = "org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable"
    SPARK_SQL_FORMAT = "org.elasticsearch.spark.sql"

    NODE_KEY = "es.nodes"
    PORT_KEY = "es.port"
    RESOURSE_KEY = "es.resource"
    QUERY_KEY = "es.query"
    JSON_INPUT_KEY = "es.input.json"
    MAPPING_ID_KEY = "es.mapping.id"
    WRITE_OPERATION_KEY = "es.write.operation"
    MAPPING_DATE_KEY = 'es.mapping.date.rich'
    # endregion

    def __init__(self):
        ''' Declare sparkContext, sqlContext
        '''

        # region Declare spark configurations
        CONF = SparkConf().setAppName(
            'fetchingTransactions').setMaster('local[*]')
        self.sparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=CONF)
        self.SqlContext = SQLContext(self.sparkContext)
        # endregion

        # get elasticsearch configurations
        self.__host = getenv('ES_HOST') or "localhost"
        self.__port = getenv('ES_PORT') or 9200

    def getDataFrame(self, index, query=None):
        """Bring the whole Elasticsearch index as Spark DataFrame

        Arguments:
            index {str} -- Index Name
            query {str} -- Elastic query

        Returns:
            DataFrame -- Spark DataFrame

        Raises:
            Error -- may raise unexpected types of errors
        """
        excluded = [
            "iD",
            "isXmlTrail",
            "xmlException",
            "dateTimeFrom",
            "dateTimeTo",
            "xmlAsJson.*.ACTION",
            "xmlAsJson.*.AT_ACTION_DATE",
            "xmlAsJson.*.AT_ROW_ID",
            "xmlAsJson.*.AT_USERNAME",
            "xmlAsJson.*.AT_REQUEST_ID",
            "xmlAsJson.*.AT_OS_USER",
            "xmlAsJson.*.AT_TERMINAL"
        ]
        reader = self.SqlContext.read.format(self.SPARK_SQL_FORMAT)\
            .option("es.read.field.exclude", str.join(",", excluded))\
            .option("es.read.field.as.array.include", "xmlAsJson")\
            .option("es.mapping.date.rich", False)\
            .option("es.http.timeout", "10m")\
            .option("es.http.retries", "10")\
            .option(self.NODE_KEY, self.__host)\
            .option(self.PORT_KEY, self.__port)\

        if query:
            reader = reader.option("es.query", query)

        return reader.load("{}/{}".format(index, index))
```

and i am getting this error:

> [An error occurred while calling o33.load. :
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source:
> org.elasticsearch.spark.sql. Please find packages at
> http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
> at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
> at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)
> ... 13 more ]

I tried modifying the data from in elastic but it did not work.